# CKeditor and Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor, razorengine

Does anyone knows how to implement **razor syntax** to be rendered when using **CKediotr**. I want to enter **c#** code in CKEditor but Im not able to do that because it renders all content as a text.

Sample:

I want to enter e.g. @DateTime.Now.Year inside ckeditor.

and other more complex types.

Thanks,

Comment: You want in the view to use razor syntax or when the site is started to write c# ?

Comment: In the view. ;)

Answer (score -1):

TinyMCE, (F)CKEditor, et al are HTML editors, and are not designed for C# (or PHP, ASP, CFM...) functions. While you could possible right something for evaluating the text and figuring out what you need to do, it becomes a royally complex PIA. There are two ways that I have seen that work with decent results.

The first method would be to have the output from your (CK) Editor saved as a partial view, and then calling that inside of a parent view. The problem with this method is that if someone who does not know Razor makes an error it will kill the page. Same thing occurs for other programming errors.

The second method would be to create placeholders for common items, and then doing an evaluation method for replacements.

```
string BodyContent = GetPageContent(PageID); // whatever to grab CKEditor content
BodyContent = BodyContent.Replace("##Year##", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
// other replacements here
```

And then on the view you would just call that variable accordingly. It is limited as to what you can do, but that isn't always a bad thing.